# Using SVG with ajax to animate state of IO hardware

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, animation, svg

The company I'm working for is selling micro computers that can manage and monitor diffrent IO devices.
They are using ajax for the web IO stuff and I created a new graphic for a Voltmeter that contains 41 states from 0 Volt to 20 with 0,5 stepping.
My first question would be, if that is being called a sprite because there are so many images?

The code I wrote to load the images was already much shorter than the company's because I made a function to generate the img links via a counter.

```
var i = 1;

function counter()
{
var img = "http://"adress"/"+i.toString()+".png";

if (i == 40)
    {
    i=0;
    }
i++;
document.getElementById('picture').src = img;
}
```

now the next step I was asked was doing that with a svg.

I could do the same thing with a svg of course, but I´ve read about being able to animate svg.

The first big question is:
Should I make a svg file that contains all 41 images as code or should I just do one image and animate the needle by creating an own pivot for it?

Note that the animation states would be hand in hand with a javascript code that "GET"s hex values via xmlHTTP which define the states of the device.
So i wanna turn the needle to 3 volts on the svg if I rotate the knob at the device.
I don't ask for a full solution but some hints if this would even be possible and what i need to read about.

Here is the img I am talking about as an example
[Voltmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M89oP.png)

https://www.deviantart.com/blue-lovag/art/Voltmeter-759876423

Comment: Please write only what is relevant to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SVG with 41 groups in it might be a big file. If you create an SVG containing just one image, where the needle is a `<g>` group with an ID defined on it, you can refer to that group from JavaScript and have the needle rotate -- even with a smooth animation.

You might define a CSS class for each state the needle can be in, with the rotation in it:

```
.pos20 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

There are some gotchas with Internet Explorer support for this, so you may have to set an attribute on the group directly:

```
<g transform="rotate(45deg)">...</g>
```

Please refer to [this article](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/) on CSS-Tricks for details on SVG transformations.

Comment: now that sounds much more elegant and surprisingly not that complicated, thank your very much!